# Trying to use Group info from Facebook API

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-graph-api

I want to access the Group section of the Facebook API. However, it’s blocked behind requiring App Review. According to FB, I should have a thoroughly tested app before putting it under review?

How am I supposed to have a tested app and be ready for release if I don’t even have the API endpoints? Am I understanding this correctly?

As of right now, if I query anything Group related I get an OAuthException code 1.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

> but we recommend that you begin a submission only after you have thoroughly tested your app in development mode and you are ready for release.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/

> As of April 4, 2018, this edge returns empty data sets for GET operations unless the calling app has gone through App Review. This applies to GET operations using /me/groups as well. Please see the Groups API section of the Breaking Changes changelog for more information.

Comment: With an app in dev mode, I can get the list of the groups I am a member off no problem, after granting the necessary permissions. Basic group info such as cover and description are also available. Some of the rest requires group admin access, like reading the feed or accessing the member count. So if you need any of that stuff – create your own group that your app admin is also an admin of, then you should be able to test whatever you need to build your app.

Comment: What about getting access to information of public groups which I’m not a part of? Will that be available after it goes under app review?

Comment: Depends on what specific info you actually want, I suppose. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/group#read, reading most of those public fields should not even require submission for the Group API feature to begin with, that mostly applies when you are talking secret/closed groups, or access to actual member info.

Comment: Trying to use this request,
`https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/119340071470811`,


I get this error: 
`Unsupported get request. Object with ID '119340071470811' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.`

Do you have a working query that I may be able to try?

Comment: What exactly is that ID supposed to represent?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It's the ID of a Group that my user is a part of. I've tried public groups and private groups that I'm both a part of and not a part of.

Comment: What permissions does your access token include? You’ll need at least `groups_access_member_info`.

Comment: I don't have that token, but after applying for it, it seems like it's only applicable to groups that I'm a part of, is that correct? The nature of what I want to build requires me to access groups that I'm not involved with. I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: I’m not sure either, the documentation does not seem to be definitive about that. But I’d expect that if it was, you would need to submit your app for access to the Group API feature first of all. Although the description of the uses cases here also all seem to focus on groups the user is a member of, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#reference-GROUPS_ACCESS

Comment: I can't even get to the ones i'm a member of tho, only created.